# FreeBSD package version info

Tags: perl, freebsd

I have a script, which is written in perl, that gathers information about packages that are installed via ports. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem there is a functional, simple way to determine what version the port is. Granted, you can use this:

```
pkg_version -v
```

This will show you all the packages, the symbol related to their state (needs to be updated, succeeds ports, etc.) and the version it is.

Since this is in a script, I really do not want to do this:

```
my $blah = "pkg_version -v | grep -vE '(up-to-date|succeeds)'|awk '{print \$1}'";
# Then make a var and run it through with backticks.
```

Which would give me a list of all the packages, to allow me to turn it into an array, then do some magic with it. What I would like to do is this just figure out what the version of the package is whereas the name of the package is provided.

Again, I can do this with pipes, awk, etc. but I do not want to if I can avoid it.

Please let me know what you guys can come up with as I am finding this to be quite difficult to find info on.

P.S. Here is some info:

FreeBSD version: 9.1
Arch: x64
Perl version: 5.14.2 (amd64-freebsd-thread-multi)

If someone can add a tag for ports, that'd be great since it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can examine the package database in `/var/db/pkg` directly using `opendir`/`readdir`.

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to utilizing the directory name to determine the version, right? For example, package "blah" has directory "blah-1.1.1_3"

Comment: Yes that's right. It assumes the `pkg_*` tools have done their housekeeping properly, but if you allow for them getting this wrong then you have a whole host of other possible problems.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is of course the nature of the beast. I'll need to do my duty of course and write some fancy sanity checks to ensure this doesn't go haywire. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Working on this for a little while now, I am not so sure I like this method. It's unfortunately a tad unreliable, i.e., say we have blah-1.2.3.4_1 and bleh-1.4.3.2, this requires a large regex build up that might prove to be futile. Any other ideas which could be ran via pkg_\* scripts as arguments?

Comment: @RubyisChai: Why isn't it a simple matter of `my ($pkg, $ver) = split /-/`?

Comment: Well, I could do that, although that "could" be a revision number. If you check svnweb and go to devel/gmake you'll see you have PORTVERSION= and PORTREVISION?= -- I don't want to strip that off as it could be important. I am trying to find this info, but if you know it, it would be very good to know. What does the "," and "-" mean? Are they for revision? i.e. "xorg-libraries-7.3_1" and "libX11-1.1.3,1"; notice the comma and underscore in the names? I can't find good info on what they mean to the version.

Comment: Was giving [this URL](http://docs.freebsd.org/doc/4.5-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/x387.html) to explain commas and underscores in pkg names.